# Tailwind CSS how to code pixel perfect design

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Just started to use https://tailwindcss.com

And can't figure out how to code pixel perfect design only with tailwind classes. Simple example, I need padding-left  22px but closest tailwind class is pl-6 and pl-8 which is 24px and 32px respectively. So at the end of the day, I have a bunch of tailwind classes + 1 custom where I make arrangements this defeats the purpose of this framework "utilities first".

Comment: You'll never get pixel perfect designs from a framework unless the design is created specifically with that framework's abilities/expectations in mind.

Comment: I don't agree with you, or maybe I would say "You'll never get pixel perfect designs from a framework which don't have any customization capabilities" :) As for this framework I think that could be done inside tailwind.config.js so you can specify whatever size you want.

Comment: Sure you can always hack the framework but that's assuming your designer always uses equal column widths, standardized font sizes, padding, etc, etc, etc. The reality is that pixel perfection is super expensive and framework consistency most likely at odds with a designer's "gut" placement.

Comment: Glad you figured out how to solve it here!

Comment: You actually should not want to have a "pixel-perfect" design, that is a [completely antiquated paradigm](https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2017/stop-using-the-term-pixel-perfect/) that should've stopped being used 15 years ago. You cannot control what the browser, screen&viewport size, resolution, browser zoom, OS zoom, custom font-size, etc. will be for the user that views your product. It doesn't make any sense to try to make it "pixel perfect" anymore when we should instead be aiming for dynamic sites that look good under any condition, not static sites that always look just like the Photoshop.

Comment: As a pixel-perfect practitioner for 10+ years, I would highly NOT recommend using Tailwind for pixel-perfect projects. I get how tempting Tailwind is for devs that are not (and/or reluctant to be) familiar with css/scss. It is in my opinion still a disaster for the entire coding world. I'm saying this without testing. I've done several projects with tedious HTML thanks to Tailwind and spending even more time clearing up the HTML file than the time I spent on css. Also seeing a pattern that the backend devs I hire prefer Tailwind and those good at frontend don't.

Comment: @StephenMIrving actually 'dynamic sites that look good under any condition' are considered in perfect pixel design nowadays. At least in the working environment where I have been.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Ok got it, I need to edit `tailwind.config.js` and set custom sizes there. For example:

```js
height: [
  ...
  '278px': '278px',
  ...
]
```

So now this size can be set with `<div clas="h-278px">...</div>`

**Update:**

After completed many projects on top of TailwindCSS I learned that it's not very optimal to set spacing/w/h... in tailwind config if it's used only once. It's better to go with the custom class you can always use @apply in that class anyway.

**Update 2021:**

As of tailwind version 2.1 we can enable JIT and use arbitrary styles like this:

```
mb-[278px]
```

Comment: I would go with custom style for that specific purpose

Comment: is there a way to define the pixel dynamically? `class = "h-23px "` that number 23px or anyother pixel be create dynamically

Comment: Currently no, but this would need some kind of reverse compiling, from HTML/JS/PHP to CSS. Similar like PurgeCSS works.

Comment: From now, we can implement pixel perfect design with help of tailwindcss-jit library.
They use square bracket notation like <div class="h-[278px]">...</div>

Comment: thanks endmaster! wow , jit comes built in now. In Nuxt, I just had to add mode:'jit' to the config. And now its so smart and fast, just creates the css needed!

Answer (score 32):

You can try this for px and % styling -

```css
w-[100px] or w-[50%]
```

Answer (score 6):

Has mention by  [Mladen Janjetovic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54618144/tailwind-css-how-to-code-pixel-perfect-design#comment104131312_54619295), you can also add new [utilities](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities) to you tailwind setup.
The easiest way to add your own utilities to Tailwind is to simply add them to your CSS.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .h-278 {
    height: 278px;
  }
}
```

So now this height can be set with

```
<div clas="h-278">...</div>
```

By using the `@layer` directive, Tailwind will automatically move those styles to the same place as `@tailwind utilities` to avoid unintended specificity issues.
Using the `@layer` directive will also instruct Tailwind to consider those styles for purging when purging the utilities layer.

Comment: I didn’t get it, why use this if we have tailwind.config.js?

Comment: @RomkaLTU the main raison is it is the [recommended way](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities)  of adding custom utilities by the creators of tailwind. the second no less interesting reason is with this method you can [generate responsive variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities#generating-responsive-variants) witch let you do for exemple `<div clas="m:h-278">...</div>`

Comment: But h is not custom utility, custom utility is "really-custom-utility". h, w, p and other generating from spacing property.

Comment: This doesn't quite work and im only trying to place a red border like this: 
```@layer utilities {
    .red {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}```