# How can I specify exactly 600px width in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

In Tailwind [Officail docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width), there are lots of width utilities we can use.

However, the **maximum fixed width** I can specify is `w-96`, which is `width: 24rem; (384px)`

I've noticed a weird class called `w-px`, at first glance, I thought I can do `w-600px`, but it's not working, it is exactly `1px`.

I am currently migrating my old project to Tailwind CSS, so there are going to have lots of weird widths I need to specify, but Tailwind CSS doesn't provide them by default.

If I can just do `w-600px` would be nice, or am I missing any other better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54618144/tailwind-css-how-to-code-pixel-perfect-design

Comment: The docs are incomplete for Tailwind. I've posted on their GH discussion to request more examples for properties that use `px` values.

Comment: For those who might be checking for max-width, check https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width and https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you configure your Tailwind install to run in just-in-time mode, and you are running tailwind 2.1+, you can use their arbitrary value support. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

For example, I needed a width of 600px, here is how I specified it:

`w-[600px]`

Comment: This seems more elegant than the accepted answer.

Comment: Excellent! This is the best route for one-off values because it makes no sense to pollute the config just for one value.

Comment: A nit that everyone is reading through, but `w-[600px]`.

Answer (score 21):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

#1 You need to add the below code in tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
     extend: {
       width: {
        '600': '600px',
       }
    }
  }
}
```

#2 After that you can use `w-600` in your HTML file like below.

```
<div class="w-600">...</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You were just missing the brackets [ ]. Try this:

```
w-[600px]
```

Comment: This was answered in the top answer....

Comment: The top answers uses height with `h-`, so this might be confusing for someone who wants to know "exactly 600px width in Tailwind CSS."

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the section "Arbitrary values" that most part of Tailwind classes have. There you can see how you can set any value you want.

Arbitrary values for with https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#arbitrary-values

> If you need to use a one-off width value that doesn’t make sense to include in your theme, use square brackets to generate a property on the fly using any arbitrary value.

```
<div class="w-[600px]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```